# round lots in algorithmic trading

Tags: market-data

In an automated strategy, is one restricted to buying round lots of 100 shares ? If so, 100 shares of google would be on the order of 100K. Is it possible to tell the broker that you don't want to buy round lots of certain stocks. Thanks.

Comment: you may even be able to trade fractional shares these days

Answer (score 1):

Looks like my comment was completely wrong. Rounds lots are no longer required.